# PagerAdapter don't attach to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have follow view structure:

```
<RecyclerView>

    <CardView>
        <RecyclerView id:="inner_recycler">
        </RecyclerView>
    </CardView>

    <CardView>
        <ViewPager id:="pager_1">
        </ViewPager>
    </CardView>

    <CardView>
        <ViewPager id:="pager_2">
        </ViewPager>
    </CardView>

    <CardView>
        <ViewPager id:="pager_3">
        </ViewPager>
    </CardView>

</RecyclerView>
```

RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class TodayStatsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Map<Date, StatsBean> mStats;
    private Context mContext;

    public TodayStatsAdapter(Context context, Map<Date, StatsBean> stats) {
        mStats = stats;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position > 0) {
            return R.layout.today_stats_other_item;
        } else {
            return R.layout.today_stats_first_item;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
        if (R.layout.today_stats_first_item == viewType) {
            return new TodayFirstStatsHolder(view);
        } else {
            return new TodayOtherStatsHolder(view, mContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        List<Date> listDate = new ArrayList<>(mStats.keySet());
        Collections.sort(listDate, Date::compareTo);

        if (holder instanceof TodayFirstStatsHolder) {
            TodayFirstStatsHolder viewHolder = (TodayFirstStatsHolder) holder;
            final Date lastDate = listDate.get(listDate.size() - 1);
            final StatsBean bean = mStats.get(lastDate);
            viewHolder.setDateTime(mContext.getString(R.string.stats_today_text)+ " " + lastDate.getHours() + ":" + lastDate.getMinutes());
            viewHolder.initRecycler(bean);
        }

        if (holder instanceof TodayOtherStatsHolder) {
            TodayOtherStatsHolder viewHolder = (TodayOtherStatsHolder) holder;
            final Date lastDate = listDate.get(position - 1);
            final StatsBean bean = mStats.get(lastDate);
            viewHolder.setDateTime(mContext.getString(R.string.stats_today_text)+ " " + lastDate.getHours() + ":" + lastDate.getMinutes());
            viewHolder.initPager(bean);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mStats.size();
    }

    public static class TodayFirstStatsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mItemDateText;
        private RecyclerView mItemRecyclerView;
        private Context mContext;

        public TodayFirstStatsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();
            mItemDateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_item_date_text);
            mItemRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_item_recycler_view);
        }

        public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
            mItemDateText.setText(dateTime);
        }

        public void initRecycler(StatsBean bean) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext) {
                @Override
                public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            mItemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            mItemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            TodayStatsFirstItemAdapter adapter = new TodayStatsFirstItemAdapter(bean, mContext);
            mItemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    public static class TodayOtherStatsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mItemDateText;
        private ViewPager mItemViewPager;
        private Context mContext;


        public TodayOtherStatsHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            mContext = context;
            mItemDateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_item_date_text);
            mItemViewPager = itemView.findViewById(R.id.other_item_pager);
            mItemViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
            mItemDateText.setText(dateTime);
        }

        public void initPager(StatsBean bean) {
            TodayStatsOtherItemPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new TodayStatsOtherItemPagerAdapter(
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    bean.getStats()
            );
            mItemViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class TodayStatsOtherItemPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> mEntriesStats;

    public TodayStatsOtherItemPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Map<String, Integer> stats) {
        super(fm);
        mEntriesStats = new ArrayList<>(stats.entrySet());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TodayStatsPagerFragment.newInstance(mEntriesStats.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mEntriesStats.size();
    }

}
```

The first RecyclerView has an adapter which creating CardView with a RecyclerView or a ViewPager. The inner RecyclerView is initializing and working normally. Every ViewPagers have own PagerAdapters and ViewHolders. The "pager_1" is creating and inflating normally but other pagers don't attached own adapters and therefore don't show information. Why did adapters demonstrate such behavior? How to do that every ViewPager will attach own adapter?

Sorry for my bad English. I hope you will help me.

Comment: Pasting your code would definitely help.

Comment: @VishalArora added RecyclerView adapter

Comment: The problem is actual.